# command line variable does not increment on build script

Tags: command-line, teamcity

For teamcity. The output of code below, passcount is '0' but it should be 4 based on I know it is doing 4 passes. command line script (abbreviated):

```
result=0
passcount=0
for layer in %project.layers%; do
   //     some stuff...
 result=$?
 if [[ "$result" -ne 0 ]]; then
    break;
 else
    passcount++
    echo " $layer Succeeded"
 fi
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take passcount++ into double brackets, i.e. ((passcount++))

Comment: This apparently did it!